# WindowBeforeRightClick - PowerPoint 2007

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

I'm attempting to add a Context Menu option to PowerPoint 2010 that only appears when text is selected. Unfortunately the WindowBeforeRightClick event does not seem to fire if the mouse is inside of a TextBox.

Is there a different event I need to be listening to or a better way to add that context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the first answer on [this](http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/mv/msg/142782/0/0/) Forum-Thread this is an issue that is known to Microsoft, but has not yet been fixed.

We are experiencing the same issue here.
Our current work-around is to use the WindowSelectionChange-Event. However, this will only work if you want to ensure that a **TextBox** has to be selected, as the SelectionChange-Event will only fire when you select a new shape.